# Do signifiers in a "system of signs" refer to each other, as well as the signified?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-language, structuralism

Saussure [claimed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_in_General_Linguistics) that language is "a system of signs that express ideas."

[image]

- Handbook of Semiotics, By Winfried Nöth, p57.

Do these signs, in language or any of the sign systems just mentioned, refer *to each other* (as well as the signified) in order to make the system?

What does e.g. Saussure say on this?

---

I think *maybe*.

When I say the phrase "the tree is green", the terms don't obviously refer to each other. But a language, [langue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue_and_parole), is governed by rules, e.g. definitions, which can be expressed in terms of reference. As when a dictionary defines a word: it refers to it.

Assuming that the **whole** of a language can be so defined, then a system of signs can be exhaustively expressed by terms referring to other terms: it ***is*** those references.

- Can any "system of signs" be completely defined?

Regardless of whether it is *made* by that exhaustive definition.

Comment: Signs belong to a *system* because they are related to each other.

Comment: sure, i'm asking about reference tho

Comment: reference is a relation, i think ?

Comment: [Signifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_in_General_Linguistics#The_sign) for S stands for *sign*; the signified, or concept, can be the "reference".

Comment: i'm not sure why you think this answers my question, so am not sure i understand? *can* the signifier be what is referred to? i think so. the phrase *the term "my apple"* refers to a sign 'my apple'. i think, unless ofc concepts are all there are to the signs as they make up a phrase @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: I can't say for sure, because I haven't read Sassure, but I believe "my apple" is considered two signs, for no other reason than that native speakers consider them to be two signs/words.  If memory serves, signs can stand alone, and be identified as having meaning, thought the particulars of that meaning often require the context from the system of signs.  One can contrast this with the radicals of Chinese writing.  Multiple radicals are put together to form one character.  A character has meaning, but the individual radicals are not considered to have a meaning.

Comment: Of course, you cannot define all the terms in a language without circularity: you have to start somewhere. The language does not work that way: children do not learn language via definitions, and scarcely new words are learned by us via definitions. Language learning and usage is the best support to the idea of languge as a "system": we learn it using it in the communication process. We lear what is a screwdriver not thorugh a definition, but seeing someone using it to fix a screw. In the same way, we lear the language hearing our parents.

Comment: so a struct formal language is impossible?

Comment: signs are always circular. Systems are closed and all signs within a system refer to signs within the same system. Referring to 'military signals' within the system of 'language' is a sign within 'language'. 'Military signals' does not need to exist within 'language'; all that exists within 'language' is the sign. A system of signs can only be defined within itself.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA why think that it's viciously circular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Strictly, a formal language has a fully defined vocabulary and syntax.

- International Encyclopedia of Linguistics, Volume 4, p2

Not sure if a formal language can be completely defined in its own terms. Why not though, assuming that its definition is in a language which can be translated into it?

Comment: sorry if that's nonsense, just thinking out loud really

Comment: For some (many? all?) computer languages, even the formal specifications include conditions where the output/result is undefined so that different compilers (or different architectures) result in different program behavior if one of these undefined operations are used. http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213.

Comment: ok, not sure what you are getting at tho :) you're saying that "it has a precise and finite definition" (wikipedia) but it isn't fully defined ? @Dave

Comment: In the semiotic sense signification bears meaning, signs talk about *stuff*.  Formal languages do not have semantics, they have only syntax, and their semantics are by analogy with some real domain they were constructed to model.  So I am pretty sure a formal language 'signifies' only in the broader context of itself and the systems it models, and then it signifies primarily those external things.